# browserify fails to parse jsx despite using babel-preset-react, babel-preset-es2015 and babel-preset-stage-3

Tags: reactjs, gruntjs, babeljs, browserify, babelify

I am using grunt to automate the whole process. This is what my configuration looks like:

```
browserify: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                '<%= dirs.dest %>/index.js': [
                    '<%= dirs.src %>/index.js'
                ]
            },
            options: {
                transform: [
                    ['babelify', { presets: ['es2015', 'stage-3', 'react'] }]
                ]
            },
        }
    },
```

It fails when attempting to parse one of the react components that are imported with the following error:

```
>>             <div>
>>             ^
>> ParseError: Unexpected token
Warning: Error running grunt-browserify. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I've tried using the same file that throws the error with babel-standalone in the browser and it works just fine.

I'm stumped as to how to fix this as most links say that using babel-preset-react should fix it (and it works with another project that I have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, browserify does not transpile included files that are outside your project. Since the component that was causing the issue was being included from `node_modules`, I had to configure its `package.json` file to ensure that browserify knew that its source was **not** transpiled and that it had to transpile it when it was being included.

I was able to do that by including this in my `node_modules` component's `package.json`:

```
"browserify": { "transform": [ "babelify" ] }
```

Once I added this and ensured that the component was being exported from the module, everything started working as expected.

Reference: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1625#issuecomment-105334250

Answer (score 0):

Try babel-preset-env, this should cover most cases.
Personally I tend to use something like:
`"presets": ["env", "react", "stage-3"]`

if this doesn't work, it must be something else with your config

Comment: can you paste the code of the component that fails?

Comment: This is it https://github.com/fabianTMC/react-SVGPieTimer/blob/master/svgPieTimer.js

Comment: Ah, well you need to `import React from 'react'` at the top.

Comment: That didn't fix it but I was able to track down the reason why: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1625#issuecomment-105334250